# permit_mynetworks overrides check_sender_access?

Tags: postfix

I am configuring a postfix relay hosted on a cloud provider. I would like to allow relay access only to public IPs of my company and to a precise list of senders. So here are my main.cf configurations:

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 1.2.3.4/23 4.5.6.7/32 7.8.9.1/24
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,
                                check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/allowed_senders,
                                reject_unauth_destination
```

allowed_senders is like this:

```
name.surname@domain.com OK
john.doe@domain.com OK
andrew.white@domain.com OK
```

If I keep these settings, allowed_senders is ignored, whether I put it before or after permit_mynetworks settings. If I remove permit_mynetworks, allowed_senders works normally.

So, how do I restrict access to this relay by source IP address and sender email address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got an answer asking to Postfix mailing list. Here is the working configuration:

**main.cf**

```
 mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 1.2.3.4/23 4.5.6.7/32 7.8.9.1/24

 # No relaying from untrusted networks
 smtpd_relay_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks,
    reject_unauth_destination

 # Also, no relaying by unauthorized senders
 smtp_sender_restrictions =
     check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/allowed_senders,
     reject_unauth_destination

 # Apply UCE controls to remote clients
 smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
     permit_mynetworks,
     ... anti-spam rules if any ...
```

**allowed_senders:**

```
 # Just in case, reject relay attempts from untrusted networks
 #
 name.surname@domain.com permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination
 john.doe@domain.com     permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination
 andrew.white@domain.com permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination
```